# Выяснить значность int элемента в C#

Tags: c#

Как выяснить какое количество символов находится в int переменной, если нет ограниченнее на значность числа т.е. в переменной может быть как и двухзначное значение так и пятизначное. Как можно это грамотно реализовать в C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте логарифм:

```
int x = ...;

int decimalPlaces = 1 + (int)Math.Log10(x);
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ добрый человек

Comment: Почему бы сразу не кастануть в int? Truncate выглядит излишеством.

Comment: А знак +/- не учитывается?

Comment: @aepot Да, действительно. Проверил [тут](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yht2cx7b.aspx): `When you convert a double or float value to an integral type, this value is rounded towards zero to the nearest integral value`